# Cannot locate executable through symbolic link

Tags: command-line, python, python3, symbolic-link, executable

I'm new to Linux/Mac OS in it's entirety, but I've learned a lot the last few days.

My NativeScript app builds using the `python` command, but my system only has python3 installed.
That is all fine, and in the [nativescript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios) it is stated that a symbolic link will do the trick.

So I made that link using the following command; `sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python` (/usr/local/bin is in my PATH).
But executing `python -V` throws the error; `python: error: Failed to locate 'python'.`

I have seen several posts, none which helped me out.
I verified that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/executable-symbolic-link-results-in-command-not-found) isn't the problem running the following commands;

```
which python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
which python -> /usr/local/bin/python
python3 -V -> Python 3.8.9
python -V -> python: error: Failed to locate 'python'.
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python -> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  16 Jul  7 12:17 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3
```

How can I make the python command use python3 using a symbolic link?

Comment: The error message `python: error: Failed to locate 'python'` is definitely printed by `python` itself, not by `bash`. It means that when you run `python -V`, `bash` finds `python` and runs it, but `python` cannot locate itself. Can it be that `python` uses a different search path than your shell, which doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`, thus it can't find itself?

Comment: Are you using MacOS? Because you mentioned MacOS in your question. This is not a proper site to ask MacOS questions, it is dedicated for Ubuntu only. However, there seems to be a similar problem as yours asked on StackOverflow and from the answer it looks that you need an additional symbolic link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345515/mac-os12-4-python-error-failed-to-locate-python

Comment: @raj That worked like a charm, thank you. Not sure if you want your answer to be accepted or my question marked as duplicated but I'll leave that to you guys.
Meanwhile I used the answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/230689/launching-executable-from-usr-local-bin-needs-access-to-local-file?rq=1 to address my issue successfully, but your linked answer is even better. Also thanks for letting me know I'm posting on the wrong board :)